# Why do objects move around separately even after parenting?

Tags: parent

I was following the good ol' doughnut tutorial on Youtube and came across a quick problem.

After assigning Child & Parent connections from the 'Icing' and 'Bun' I found that when grabbing the object, the icing moves around on it's own even though the two are now connected.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> makes them both one shape, but in this instance I would like to keep the objects separate.

In the tutorial after setting the Child and Parent, he is able to move both around and fixed together. I will attach a link to the video.

https://youtu.be/ZTxBrjN1ugA?t=210

I have attached an image also detailing the problem, any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The icing is a child of the bun, and so it can move freely. But if you move the bun, the icing will move too

Comment: @Gorgious That's the thing, it moves around like this regardless of which object i select first

Comment: Disconnecting the Child and Parent and re attaching them in a different order allowed them to move as one object. Also the Plane was stuck to my doughnut when trying to move it originally, but found out I had left Proportional Editing on so it was radius moving everything in an area, derp!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure proportional editing (hotkey <kbd>O</kbd>) is turned off.

Comment: I feel like a fool now.

Answer (score 1):

When this happens, you may have accidentally checked one of the Transform options in the N panel.

Check here:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

You might consider applying scale and rotation to both, then using the world origin (where the 3D cursor is after pressing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>C</kbd> as the origin of both objects (*Object > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor*).

Then both objects should move in sync. You can always change object origin to edit.

Comment: This is a terrible answer. It is wrong and - what's even worse - misleading. Transforms of the objects do not have any effect in how object hierarchy is intended to work.